# Does anyone know of a iOS 3rd party framework for managing documents like 'Paper'?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm looking for a framework that offers something simpler to the books in the app 'Paper'

[image: paper]

It is a fairly common UI. So before I spend the next few hours to coding something myself. I thought I would check to see if anyone had already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iCarousel with some images from the photos.app + a mask (rectangle with top-right and bottom-right corners rounded off) + overlay image for the strap of the binder = Paper.

iCarousel: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: cheers saved me a couple of hours on monday morning.

Answer (score 4):

There is a commercial library that does a bit more than what you need.
It basically mimic the entire Paper UI, including the 3D pages & the animations.
It has many customization options, and surely can do what you need and more.

It's called PepperUI. http://www.binpress.com/c/960/11778?slk

[Disclaimer: I'm the author of this component. Sorry for a bit of shameless advertising, but it still answers the question]